# Nullpointerexception thrown when webpage kept open for long time

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm developing a website using JSP and Servlets using Apache - tomcat 5.5 as server.
My application runs fine. But whenever I leave any webpage open and return back to it after some time say 30minutes, and click on any button or icon, it throws error sayin -

```
Sep 16, 2011 2:11:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.homepage_jsp._jspService(homepage_jsp.java:107)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your session is timing out. You need to either force the user to login again, or extend your session timeout.

You can change the session timeout by editing your web.xml and adding:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Which will give you a session timeout of 60 minutes. -1 means there is no timeout.

Comment: Top tip: Change it to 2 minutes or something, and see if you have the same problem after two minutes. Otherwise you'll have to wait for an hour :-)

Comment: Can Tomcat persist sessions transparently?

Comment: It's good to check if the session still avaliable before use it.

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution. The same problem would still occur after 60 minutes of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.apache.jsp.homepage_jsp._jspService(homepage_jsp.java:107)
> ```

The symptom that this only occurs after a long time indeed indicates that the session has been timed out. But changing the session timeout is not the right solution. You have actually a **bug** in your JSP.

Because you're using old fashioned JSP *scriptlets* `<% %>` instead of normal Java classes such as [servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) to control the request/response and do the business stuff in the JSP, it's harder to naildown the root cause of the `NullPointerException`. You need to open the generated `homepage_jsp.java` in server's work directory and head to line 107 and finally trackback this line into your `homepage.jsp` so that you can fix the bug.

Perhaps you need to do a `request.getSession()` instead of `request.getSession(false)`, or you need to check if a session attribute is not `null` before accessing it, etcetera.